# Is it possible to deploy Azure Synapse workspace roles with arm?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-synapse

Is there a way to use arm template to automatically deploy workspace roles, e.g. workspace admin assigning an object Id. I can't find any relevant resources online and it is not so well documented. I could already successfully assign roles to the data lake and other services. I can't seem to find the arm template Provider for workspace level assignment. I would be happy if someone could give me an example or clarify if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

ARM template is designed for management APIs and not data for plane APIs. Role assignment APIs belong to data plane. AFAIK, we cannot use ARM template for data plane APIs